# How to save data from Google to our server?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have connected with Google drive by Google API on my WordPress website. Google drive is allow me the download permission but i want to save Google drive file on my server.

so is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. If you can download the file you can save it wherever you like, including your server.

Comment: but how i can download it at our server. can please give me some examples.

Comment: What language are you using, and what library, we have samples.

Comment: i am using php language and using google-api-php-client library.